# Doctrine is making duplicated document entries

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

I am trying to insert a embedded document into my document with the following code.

```
  // Add states, for the joining player.
  $state = new PlayerState();
  $state->setReady(false);
  $state->setPlayer($player->getId());
  $game->addPlayerState($state);

  // Save element.
  $dm->persist($game);
  $dm->flush();
```

Problem being, that this generates 2 PlayerState Document like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "513f50a58ead0ee9ac00000f" ),
  "ready" : false,
  "player" : "513f509f8ead0e8bac00000b" }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "513f50af8ead0ecdac000015" ),
  "ready" :false,
  "player" : "513f509f8ead0e8bac00000b" }
```

Am i saving this in a incorrect way? Let me know, if you need more code.

Comment: I am a bit of a doctrine noob but if you remove the flush does it work? As far as I know persist should save and flush "flushes" the current working unit, that being insert, so possibly flush is causing multiple insert here

Comment: If i skip Flush, i doesn't seem to save. I tried to flush the game, and then after set the gameState, then again do a flush. But still no luck.

Comment: nope flush saves persisted stuff you need both

Comment: What does `$game->addPlayerState($state)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick.

```
  $state = new PlayerState();
  $state->setReady(false);
  $state->setPlayer($player->getId());
  $dm->persist($state);
  $dm->flush();
  $game->addPlayerState($state);
  // Save element.
  $dm->flush();
```

This is hard to explain, but i will give it a try.
You need to persist the embedded document first, otherwise Doctrine will first persist the Document, making a embedded doc only with the values set, acting like a simple data container.

```
  $state->setReady(false);
  $state->setPlayer($player->getId());
```

After, doctrine will persist the embedded document once again, but this time looking at the Document object, assigning ID's, default values etc.

Resulting in 2 entries.

Comment: its because $state was new and didnt "really" exist, by doing flush you write it to the database and after that you can add it to $game (because then it exists)